# can't change <li> elements displayed as a table-cell to a block element and change it's width

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a `<ul>` with a width of 100% acting like a table and two `<li>` elements inside with a background-image in them,  both acting like a table-cell and each `<li>` has a width of 50%. I want to change the `<li>` to display as a block element at a media query breaking point and to be shown at 100 percent width instead. This won't work. 
This is the `HTML`:

```
 <section id="features">

<h1>The Functionality</h1>

<ul class="main-links">

<li style="background-image: url(img/test2.jpg);"><div>Some text</div></li>

<li style="background-image: url(img/test1.jpg);"><div>more text and even more text</div></li>

</ul>


</section>
```

And this is the css(Im using SASS):

```
#main #features {
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#main #features ul {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#main #features ul li {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
  height: 350px;
  list-style: none;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
```

And finally the media query:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 760px) and (max-width: 980px) {

  #features .main-links {
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 2px red;
  }

  #features li {
    border: solid 2px lime;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }


  .contact-info {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

The only thing getting override is the border...What am I missing? Appreciate the help

Comment: You need to reset the `ul` as well from `display:table` back to `block`. And also be careful about the specificity. Use the same selectors in your media query.

Comment: @Abhitalks that should probably be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: try changing its display to block and use !important where necessary. hope that helped

Comment: Adding !important do make it a block-element, but It does not change the width to 100%. That's the biggest issue I can't fix.

Comment: Ok I added !important to the width, and that solved my problem. But using !important feels wrong.

Comment: @MrAndre: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/5s72ftLq/2/

Comment: @Abhitalks: Yeah that's how I did try first time, still won't work. I have to use !important to make it work strangely  Probably something else in the css that's creating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, media queries inherit all previous styles applied to element and then overwrites the specified ones. So you need to specify every style you need to change. Otherwise `display: table` would be inherited for media query automatically.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 760px) and (max-width: 980px) {

  #features .main-links {
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 2px red;
  }

  #features li {
    border: solid 2px lime;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }


  .contact-info {
    display: none;
  }
#main #features ul {
   display: block;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your CSS styles a litte.

for UL i hide the padding to 0.

you make in the @media tag a mistake. "#features li" has to be "#features ul li"

here a jsfiddle as example that its work now: http://jsfiddle.net/3yzersdr/

```
    #features {
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#features ul {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

#features ul li {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
  height: 350px;
  list-style: none;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 760px) and (max-width: 980px) {


  #features .main-links {
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 2px red;
  }

  #features ul li {
    border: solid 2px lime;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }


  .contact-info {
    display: none;
  }
}
```